# Google Photos API limits

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to use the [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/) to incrementally upload a very large local photo library.

Everything was working, but after uploading about 1.2GB the requests started being rejected with the following message:

> Insufficient tokens for quota 'photoslibrary.googleapis.com/total_upload_bytes' and limit 'UploadBytesPerDay' of service 'photoslibrary.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXXXXX'

I checked my Photos Library API quota in the `IAM & admin` section of the Google Cloud Console and I've only used 80 out of 10,000 daily requests.

I have enough available storage space in Google Photos/Drive and the attempted uploads are fairly small (~5MB).

I'm not seeing anything in the [limits and quotes](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/api-limits-quotas) section of the API docs. Does anyone have any idea what might be blocking my requests?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about specific account support at an off-site vendor site. You should contact that vendor's support staff via their web site for questions related to your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has finally fixed this issue via [bugtracker #115932469](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115932469). The Photos API now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Google API documentations can be really confusing at times, even outdated at some parts. But they did mentioned [quota limits in here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/api-limits-quotas):

> The quota limit for requests to the Library API is 10,000 requests per
>   project per day. Requests to access media bytes (like loading a photo
>   or video) are not counted against the limit.
>
> Exceeding quota limits
>
> If the quota of requests to the Library API is exceeded, the API
>   returns an error code 429 and a message that the project has exceeded
>   the quota. For more information, see the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptonome, that quota has nothing (apparent) to do with this thread. The error message is about upload bytes, not "requests per day".

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing the exact same thing, and can find nothing at Google that even discusses any kind of upload-byte quota.

FWIW, I submitted a bug for it:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115932469